# I try to use Xdebug v3.1.0 in Mac OS X Big Sur environment, it fails to start socket, Operation now in progress (19), anyone could help me?

Tags: php, xdebug, mamp, macos-big-sur

[image: PHP and xdebug versions]

I'm trying to configure Xdebug with MAMP on Mac OS X, but there's an error in creating the socket, the firewall is disabled and I've tried several ports without success (9000, 9003, 57700...)

I list the ports using `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` and all ports tested are available.

Does anyone know what's going on?

php.ini:

```ini
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/logs"
xdebug.log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug.log"
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.24/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so"
```

xdebug.log:

```
[90419] Log opened at 2021-10-07 18:49:30.763013
[90419] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[90419] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[90419] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[90419] Log closed at 2021-10-07 18:49:30.764597
```

Comment: Is your IDE, netbeans, actually listening on that port?

Comment: *"I list the ports using `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` and all ports tested are available."* By "available" you mean that they are not listed there? In fact -- Xdebug port should be listed there -- your IDE (NetBeans? .. or is it VSCode/PhpStorm or another one) should be the one that listens on that port (remember: it's Xdebug that connects to the IDE and NOT other way around).

Comment: Derick, my netbeans is configured to use port 9003 and this port is available on the system, I think there is some security feature on MAC BIG SUR that is preventing socket creation, I don't understand what "Operation now in progress (19)" means. tks!

Comment: So what does "Operation now in progress (19)" mean? Does anyone know?